# Very thin unintended margin around divs in Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve this issue with Safari. I've not found a solution anywhere.

[image]

The output should be a whole white page and in desktop browsers (Firefox, Chrome) is correctly rendered. But in Safari (both from iPad and from iPhone) I got these annoying thin margins that let the green background show through the margins of the divs.

Oddly I got these margins also when I set "mobile device preview" in Chrome devoloper's tool.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.element1 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.element2 {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.element3 {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="element1">
</div>
<div class="element2">
</div>
<div class="element3">
</div>
```

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Chromium on Linux (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5u3os88/) while the snippets are down), so it's not really specific to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html tag correctly defined?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Zoom level?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the meta tag I definitively solved the issue. The thin margin was a scaling-related problem. In fact now that margin appears again if I zoom the website.

Comment: @Tarquiscani: I'm glad if I could help ;)